# Setting up integral with cylindrical coordinates

Tags: integration, cylindrical-coordinates

$\iiint_B \ z dxdydz$ where B is a region within cylinder $x^2+y^2 = 1$ above $xy$ plane and below cone $z=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Start by drawing a picture of this region. It should become clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The integral in the cylindrical coordinates is

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^r zr dz  dr d\theta=\frac\pi4$$